# Laravel Timestamp Validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-9

I want to make sure that the receiving data is a valid timestamp. is there a way to make sure starts_at and expired_at fields are timestamps?

```
$rules = [
    'user_id' => 'required|int|exists:users,id',
    'starts_at' => 'required|int|min:1',
    'expires_at' => 'required|int|gt:starts_at',
];
```

Comment: what do you mean by timestamp ?  you can use the `date` rule if you want to validate a date

Comment: by timestamp i mean unix timestamp as described here: [link](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20unix%20time%20stamp%3F).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `date` rule when validating timestamp. Then if you want to compare the two dates you can use the `before` and `after` rule.

```
$rule = [
    'starts_at' => 'date',
    'expired_at' => 'date|after:starts_at',
]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define the multi-format date validation in your `AppServiceProvider`

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider  
{
  public function boot()
  {
    Validator::extend('new-format', function($attribute, $value, $formats) {

      foreach($formats as $format) {

        $parsed = date_parse_from_format($format, $value);

        // validation success
        if ($parsed['error_count'] === 0 && $parsed['warning_count'] === 0) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // validation failed
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can use the custom validation rule:

`'starts_at' => 'new-format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u","Y-m-d"'`